# Reducing dataset size by one iteratively in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a dataset that I'd like to keep reducing by 1 until a certain condition. I want all the datasets saved separately and merged into a list. For example manually I could do:

```
a<-mtcars[1:nrow(mtcars),]
b<-mtcars[2:nrow(mtcars),]
c<-mtcars[3:nrow(mtcars),]
d<-mtcars[4:nrow(mtcars),]
e<-mtcars[5:nrow(mtcars),]
f<-mtcars[6:nrow(mtcars),]
g<-mtcars[7:nrow(mtcars),]
h<-mtcars[8:nrow(mtcars),]
i<-mtcars[9:nrow(mtcars),]
j<-mtcars[10:nrow(mtcars),]

as.list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)
```

Let's suppose that at the 10th row, some condition is met, such as a certain date. How could I do this iteratively? I've tried a for loop, but end up with only the last dataset as the output, not each incrementally smaller dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. no reason to repeat the n:nrow(mtcars), just pass `-(1:i)` as the rows index.
2. to include a condition, you can use an ifelse with `break()`.

For example, here is the for loop where the condition is that it will repeat this cycle 7 times:

```
  mc<-list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) ifelse(i==7,break(),mc[[i]]<-mtcars[-(1:i),])
```

Comment: How could I modify the condition to be something related to the dataframe. For instance, if I want to end the process once disp< 80

Comment: What do you mean by "once disp < 80"? Once the first row's disp is <80? replace the condition with `mtcars$disp[i+1]<80`

Comment: or, if you'd like, for example, to stop when the sum of mpg goes under 500, you can use `sum(mtcars$mpg[-(1:i)]<500`

Comment: Changing this to answer since it addressed question on condition.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with the for loop.  If you're only getting the last one back the way you're creating your results frame is wrong.

```
dataList = list()
for (i in seq(1, 10)){
    dataList[[i]] = mtcars[i:nrow(mtcars),]
}
```

changed to match edit

Comment: changed question from length to nrow to match my explanation, but still accepting this as answer.